# How to configure TinyMCE editor so that it generates styles in CSS, not HTML element attributes?

Tags: html, css, django, tinymce, mezzanine

When using TineyMCE editor to create a table, I tried to adjust the cellpadding from "table / table properties / Cell padding", and it generates an HTML table with a `cellpadding` attribute like so:

```
<table cellpadding="5">
  ...
</table>
```

which gets **easily overridden** by my other external stylesheets that contains:

```
td, th {
  padding: 0; 
}
```

Is there any way to configure TinyMCE so that it injects the styles as inline CSS?

I'm using the TinyMCE that came with installation of Django Mezzanine, which is version `4.1.10`.

Comment: You probably want to fork the table plugin and make it behave as you describe.